# how to solve this non linear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

$$
y y'(x) +y(x)^2(\sqrt {x^3}+{7\over4}\sqrt {x^5}+{1\over2}\sqrt {x^7})-{1\over2x}=0
$$

How to solve this equation??
I searched text book , and I only found bessel, legandre.
But they are not same shape with my equation.
What should I do for solving this equation?

Comment: Do a substitution $z = y^2$.

Comment: then 
$$
z'+z(2\sqrt{x^3}+{7\over2}\sqrt{x^5}+\sqrt{x^7})={1\over x}
$$
still i don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

A term of the solution of the EDO involves an integral which cannot be expressed on closed form with the standard functions (Analytical solution in attachment).

[image]

Comment: thank you thank you , I wonder that the integration can not be solved?

Comment: Of course it can be solved numerically. But as far as I know, there is no closed form with the standard functions for this integral.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide the equation by $y$, then you see that the equation is a bernoulli differential equation. You can see a general idea to solve such a differential equation in the following page.
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx